# I don't understand how the theory of algebraically closed fields admits quantifier elimination

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers, quantifier-elimination

I was reading the [wiki page about quantifier elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_elimination) and it says that the theory of algebraically closed fields  is decidable using quantifier elimination, what I understand by this is that all the formulae about that theory has an equivalent formula without quantifiers, but I don't really understand how this is possible, could someone explain to me what this concept really means, and how it can be applied to some theory?

Comment: Did you try to read the proof that the theory of algebraically closed fields admits quantifier elimination? such a proof will construct, for a given formula, an equivalent quantifier free one. Commonly, once quantifier elimination is established, one proves completeness. This is standard and can be found in many texts.

Comment: Hmm what I ask is more basic than the fact that algebraically closed fields admit quantifier elimination, I don't really understand what quantifier elimination is, does this mean that a first order theory that admits quantifier elimination could be represented completely by, say, propositional logic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example of quantifier elimination in action in the case of algebraically closed fields.  Consider the question of whether a polynomial (of degree $3$, say) has a root.  We can express this as a formula in the first-order language of rings (which is usually taken to consist of binary operations $+$ and $\cdot$, a unary operation $-$, and constants $0$ and $1$) as $$\exists x (ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0).$$
Here $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are all free variables.  Quantifier elimination says that the condition on $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, that a root exists can be expressed in the language of rings without using any quantifiers.  How do we do this?  Well, because we are in an algebraically closed field, we just need to know that the polynomial is not a nonzero constant, that is: $$\neg (a=0)\vee \neg (b=0)\vee\neg(c=0)\vee (d=0).$$

Or for a slightly more complicated example, consider the formula $$\exists x\exists y (ax^2+bx+c=0)\wedge (ay^2+by+c=0)\wedge\neg(x=y)$$
with free variables $a$, $b$, and $c$.  This says that a quadratic polynomial has two distinct roots.  In this case, we know that this is equivalent to the discriminant being nonzero (and also $a$ being nonzero, or else all the coefficients being zero), i.e. $$(\neg(a=0)\wedge\neg(b^2-4ac=0))\vee((a=0)\wedge(b=0)\wedge(c=0)).$$

In general, a quantifier-free formula must just be a Boolean combination of equations between polynomials in the free variables.  Quantifier elimination says that *any* first-order formula in some free variables is equivalent to such a quantifier-free formula.  This is a very strong and not at all obvious statement!  For the examples above it was easy, but if I give you some really complicated statement with 12 nested quantifiers, it's quite impressive to know that it is equivalent to some equalities and inequalities between polynomials in the free variables!

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean, for this to work you require your first order language to have equality and some function symbols to be interpreted as $\cdot $ and $+$, and some constants ($0,4$), right? If your language doesn't have these elements, then this is not possible (in the cases of your examples)?

Comment: I think it is pretty standard to consider equality as a logical symbol.  For algebraically closed fields, the language consists of $+$, $\cdot$, $-$, $0$, and $1$.  When I write $b^2-4ac$, that is really a shorthand for $b\cdot b+(-a\cdot c)+(-a\cdot c)+(-a\cdot c)+(-a\cdot c)$.

Comment: Could you explain a bit how $\exists x (ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0)\equiv \neg(a=0)\vee \neg(b=0)\vee \neg (c=0)\vee (d=0)$? I understand what you mean, but the part I don't get is that the latter formula doesn't seem to  be even talking about polynomials (especifically, the one with coefficients $a,b,c,d$), how can they be equivalent?

Comment: They are equivalent when interpreted in any algebraically closed field, because any nonconstant polynomial over an algebraically closed field has a root.